# springboot app takes a long time to process GET requests. time taken in DispatcherServlet.ProcessHandlerException()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets, newrelic

I have an authentication service and some controller methods to get userdetails based on id, username etc. All these HTTP.GET methods take a long time to process and New relic monitoring shows that the  DispatcherServlet.ProcessHandlerException() takes up about 70% of the time. 
I am using 4.2.1.RELEASE version of Spring. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get User Details From Id",
            notes = "Get the UserDetails object that describes the user", tags = {"/user"})
    @ApiImplicitParams({@ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "String", name = "Authorization", paramType = "header")})
    @GetMapping(value = "/users/realm/{realm}/user/{userName}", produces = Versions.V1_0)
    @Log(level = Log.Level.TRACE)
    public UserDetails getUserDetailsFromUserId(
            @ApiParam(value = "The user's details", required = true) @PathVariable(name = "realm") String realm,
            @ApiParam(value = "Include profiles in user's details") @RequestParam(name = "includeProfiles", required = false) Boolean includeProfiles,
            @PathVariable(name = "userName") String userName) {
        LOGGER.traceEntry(userName, realm, includeProfiles);
        com.nextiva.authentication.model.UserDetails result = userManagementService.getUserDetails(userName, realm, includeProfiles);
        if (includeProfiles != null && includeProfiles) {
            result.setProfiles(result.getProfiles().stream().filter(p -> NumberUtils.isDigits(p.getCorpAcctNbr()) || StringUtils.isBlank(p.getCorpAcctNbr())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
        LOGGER.traceExit();
        return userDetailsConverter.convertFromModelToV1(result);
    }
```

Example controller code has been attached.